# How Do I Separate The Salt from the Hash After Encrypting a Password with bCrypt using Java?

Tags: java, hibernate, encryption, bcrypt, password-encryption

OK, I am using Java with Spring MVC and Hibernate.  I am using bCrypt for password encryption for the first time. I understand doing in that bCrypt integrates the salt with the hash.  I have it set up currently so that the password is accepted as an input, is encoded with bCrypt, and is saved is one column of my SQL database.

However, I would like to separate the salt from the hash and put store them separately.  I have read, and tried many things, but cannot find a way to do this. So if anyone can point me in the correct direction that would be a great assistance.

This is what I have at present.

This is the basic code to setup bCrypt. It takes my password string, and encrypts it.

```
 BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();  
    String hashedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password);
```

The below code takes the password and puts it into a single column in the DB.

```
    employee.setPasswordSalt(hashedPassword);
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What benefit do you see? Or are you trying to do this just for the kicks of it?

Comment: I've been told to do this, and for the life of me cannot figure out how.

Comment: I have the actual encryption working, and from what I understand bCrypt is doing precisely what it's supposed to do. However, I was told to separate the encrypted password into 2 columns. So I'm trying to do that.

Comment: You should ask whoever told you to do that why he wants to do that. It's useless.

Answer (score 10):

While it is possible to separate the salt from the calculated BCrypt hash, there is no reason to do this. BCrypt adds the salt in plain text to the resulting hash, so the verification function `passwordEncoder.matches(...)` can extract it from there.

```
$2y$10$nOUIs5kJ7naTuTFkBy1veuK0kSxUFXfuaOKdOKf9xYT0KKIGSJwFa
 |  |  |                     |
 |  |  |                     hash-value = K0kSxUFXfuaOKdOKf9xYT0KKIGSJwFa
 |  |  |
 |  |  salt = nOUIs5kJ7naTuTFkBy1veu (22 characters)
 |  |
 |  cost-factor = 10 = 2^10 iterations
 |
 hash-algorithm = 2y = BCrypt
```

As you can see the salt is just one of several stored parameters. With extracting the salt and storing it elsewhere, you would make password verification more difficult. Furthermore if the password encoder switches to another algorithm in future, it would not be backwards compatible.

It is safe to store the salt at the same place as the hash, the salt is not a secret. If you want to add a secret to get more security, you should not make the salt a secret, instead let the salt do its job, and encrypt the resulting hash with a server side key. More about this, you can find at the end of my tutorial about [safely storing passwords](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php).

Answer (score 2):

I found out more detail for what was requested a little bit ago, and based it on that. I changed up how I encoded the password, so now it is like this...

```
    String hashedPassword = BCrypt.hashpw(password, BCrypt.gensalt());
```

and then stored it in 2 separate places like this...

```
            employee.setPasswordSalt(BCrypt.gensalt());

    employee.setPasswordHash(hashedPassword);
```

Comment: As mentioned in my answer i would advise against storing the salt elsewhere, there is absolutely nothing to gain. By the way, the method `BCrypt.gensalt()` will generate a different salt with each call, the salt stored with the employee would be useless. The `hashpw()` on the other side will still include the salt in the resulting hash, you end up with two salts at two different places.

Comment: I have noticed that, this isn't something that's going to go live so I will continue to play around with it.